# ClassNotFoundException when replacing PlatformClassLoader with AppClassLoader

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classloader, classnotfoundexception

Today I was fiddling around with the classloading mechanism of IntelliJ IDEA.
The standard flow of the start-up mechanism is as follow:

[image]

And the custom `com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader` - which loads all the IDEA-related JARs is created as follow:

[image]

The red area in the diagram shows where I modified `UrlClassLoader` creation.
Instead of having directly `PlatformClassLoader` as parent, it has `AppClassLoader` first.

In the standard flow everything works, but when I introduce `AppClassLoader` a `ClassNotFoundException` is raised in `com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner`, specifically when it tries to load `com.intellij.diagnostic.StartUpMeasurer`, which uses `it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.Object2LongMap`.

[image]

The exact exception is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:123)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2LongMap
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.start(MainRunner.java:26)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.Object2LongMap
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 7 more
```

What is happening here?